# Does HttpClientCredentialType.Windows fallback to NTLM to support non-kerberos clients?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-security

If a service endpoint is configured to use HttpClientCredentialType.Windows, then, can a client authenticate itself using NTLM?

That is, if client does not support Kerberos authentication, then will the NTLM be the automatic fallback for HttpClientCredentialType.Windows?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".